# Any way to access the plot object generated by DescTools::Desc()?

Tags: r, desctools

I am using Desc() from DescTools to describe some variables in a rmarkdown PDF document. The problem is that it generates 3 plots that are kept in line when I knit the document, thus clipping the images.

Example:

```
dates <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2021/01/01'), by="day"), 1000)

results <- DescTools::Desc(dates)

results
```

The output contains 3 plots. I can find the individual responses using the list in results[[1]]],  but I can't find the plot objects, which I think could be a way to put then one below the other.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *are* no plot objects in `results`.

Instead, when you type `results` in your console, it invokes the S3 generic `print`, which in turn dispatches the `print.Desc` method. By default, `print.Desc` will call a plotting function based on the "class" member of `results`, which in your example is `"Date"`. If you type `DescTools:::plot.Desc.Date` in your console, you will see the function that actually generates the plot every time you print `results`.

So there are no plot objects. There is data to create a plot, and whenever you print `results` to the console, the plots are created by a call to a plotting function.

The `Desc` plotting functions seem to have very few options available to allow modifications, so the best option would probably be to use the data inside `results` to create your own plots. If you wish to see the contents of `results` without the plots, simply type:

```r
print(results, plotit = FALSE)
```

And if you want the three plots one at a time, you can do:

```
DescTools:::plot.Desc.Date(results[[1]], type = 1)
```

[image]

```
DescTools:::plot.Desc.Date(results[[1]], type = 2)
```

[image]

```
DescTools:::plot.Desc.Date(results[[1]], type = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Or you avoid the rather cumbersome formulation  DescTools:::plot.Desc.Date()  and choose directly plot(results, type=1) ...